# How does the Groovy compiler work?

Tags: groovy

Can anyone explain the Groovy compiler works? Does it compile:

1. Groovy code -> Java code -> Bytecode
2. Groovy code -> Bytecode
3. Some other method

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Groovy parses the source code with [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) via the [groovy grammar description](https://github.com/apache/incubator-groovy/blob/6fe6b31816e43ae3408e2dfdbf2d2bad1a9791c0/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/antlr/groovy.g), then generates bytecode using [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/)

It does not require javac

Comment: Awesome thanks! I see I now have a little light reading for the weekend. :)

Comment: just to complete what tim said... when compiling a groovy file (or a bunch of them) the answer is right. If the Groovy compiler is supposed to compile java code as well, then it does currently the following:

 1. Groovy code -> .java stubs .
 2. javac compiles all java files.
 3. Groovy code  -> class files like above, using the javac produced classes as well.

This allows to make classes in Groovy, that use classes in Java, that use classes in Groovy (and so on). To a level in which mere separation of files in different compile steps won't work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The Groovy compiler seems to compile directly from source to bytecode:

> `groovyc` is the Groovy compiler command line tool. It allows you to
>   compile Groovy sources into bytecode. It plays the same role as `javac`
>   in the Java world.

Source: http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovyc.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand this and have used groovyc before. But this documentation does not say what the Groovy compiler does. Does it use javac under the covers perhaps?

Comment: @bholl While I can't find information to confirm it, I doubt that it does. It would be much easier to generate raw bytecode than to generate Java source that compiles to the bytecode you want.

Comment: Imagine the situation where you create a .groovy file that contains standard Java code. This isn't the ideal situation but you can do it. If groovyc did not take advantage of javac somehow under normal java code circumstances this seems like a lot of duplicate work for the groovyc compiler guys.

Comment: @bholl In that case, it may in fact utilize javac, but no Groovy code would have to pass through it.